# Логирование в C#: как вести логирование сразу во многие файлы с помощью Trace

Tags: c#, .net, логирование, io

Возможно ли с помощью `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` вести логирование сразу в несколько файлов? Хотелось бы, чтобы логи писались не в одну кучу, а логически разделялись по разным файлам. В моем случае, система содержит список ~5 разных объектов (не важно, каких). Хотелось бы, чтобы по каждому из этих объектов велся свой отдельный лог в отдельном файле.

Если так нельзя, то короткого ответа, что " `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` не позволяет так делать" будет достаточно. Тогда буду смотреть *NLog* или *log4net*, наверное. Но там (в *Trace()*-е) есть *switch* какой-то... Пока не разобрался.

Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот (поспешил задавать вопрос):

В следующем примере, как положено, `"aaaaaaaa"` отобразилось на консоле, а `"bbbbbbbb"` в указанном файле.

Не забыть `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
class Program
{
    private static TraceSource mySourceA =
        new TraceSource("TraceSourceAppA");

    private static TraceSource mySourceB =
        new TraceSource("TraceSourceAppB");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mySourceA.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
        mySourceB.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(@"C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Roaming\Skype\logs\myLog.txt"));

        RunActivities();
        Console.ReadLine();

        mySourceA.Close();
        mySourceB.Close();

        return;
    }
    static void RunActivities()
    {
        mySourceA.WriteLine("aaaaaaaa");
        mySourceB.WriteLine("bbbbbbbb");
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void WriteLine(this TraceSource source, object o)
    {
        var str = (o ?? string.Empty).ToString();

        if (source.Listeners == null || source.Listeners.Count == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("TraceSource named {0} has no listeners", source.Name));

        foreach (TraceListener listener in source.Listeners)
            listener.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;  
using System.Diagnostics;  
using System.Threading;  

namespace TraceSourceApp  
{   
    class Program  
    {  
        private static TraceSource mySource =   
            new TraceSource("TraceSourceApp");  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            Activity1();  
            mySource.Close();  
            return;  
        }  
        static void Activity1()  
        {  
            mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1,   
                "Error message.");  
            mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 2,   
                "Warning message.");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ответ у вас какой-то странный и неполный. Не видно каким образом использование TraceSource позволяет писать в несколько файлов... Наверное, стоит также рассказать как это настраивать?

Comment: хорошо, постараюсь подробнее написать

Comment: @PavelMayorov, исправил.